# Javascript Google map, show pins by longitude and latitude coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hello I have a Javascript code that shows a map with pins using there locations as adresses.
The adresses are read from an array and the array structure is like that :

```
var locations = ["1915 Edgewater Drive,Orlando,FL", "5555 Kirkman Rd.,Orlando,FL", "4965 Oak Ridge Road,Orlando,FL", "3011 E Colonial Dr,Orlando,FL", "300 Park Avenue,Winter Park,FL"];
```

The code used to show the map with the pins is as following :

```
function initialize() {
  //Planned direction display
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      polylineOptions : {
          strokeColor : 'brown',
          strokeOpacity : 0.7,
          strokeWeight : 3
      },
      suppressMarkers : true,
      suppressPolylines : true
  });

  //actual direction display
  directionsDisplayActual = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      polylineOptions : {
          strokeColor : 'brown',
          strokeOpacity : 0.7,
          strokeWeight : 3
      },
      suppressMarkers : true,
      suppressPolylines : true
  });

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': locations[0] }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.ob, results[0].geometry.location.pb);
          var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: chicago
          }
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
          map_actual = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-actual'), mapOptions);
          calcRoute();
        }
    });

}
```

Now instead of using locations with adresses I have a series of longitude and latitude coordinates like that :

```
var coordinates = [[28.378929,-80.6006008],[28.378628084853,-80.600730804958],[28.378956475407,-80.600553605881],[28.378929693408,-80.60055175679],[28.378785540514,-80.60065325285],[28.378935283517,-80.600646565422],[28.378950753943,-80.600504807166]]
```

So How can I change my code to use those coordinates instead of locations adresses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var coordinates = [[28.378929,-80.6006008],[28.378628084853,-80.600730804958],[28.378956475407,-80.600553605881],[28.378929693408,-80.60055175679],[28.378785540514,-80.60065325285],[28.378935283517,-80.600646565422],[28.378950753943,-80.600504807166]];
// loop through your array of coordinates
for(var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++){
    // create a new marker and add it to the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(coordinates[i][0], coordinates[i][1]),
        map: map
    });
}
```

Edit: You use the [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object instead of geocoding your addresses

Comment: Sorry I'm new to google maps I want to change the actual code I don't see how to use yours inside my code.

Comment: Can you show where you use your `var locations`?